# Performance issues while writing delta table to Azure-SQL database using databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks

I am trying to load roughly 20 million records from the Delta table in Databricks to the Azure SQL database using the [Apache Spark connector: SQL Server & Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16) supporting Python API and Spark 3.0.

Below is the code which I am using. Do you think I am missing something here? The same code executes fine if I am using the write format as jdbc.

```
df.write \
  .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
  .mode("overwrite") \  
  .option("truncate", "true") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable", Tablenamewithschema) \
  .option("user", user) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .option("reliabilityLevel", "BEST_EFFORT") \
  .option("tableLock", "True") \
  .option("isolationLevel", "True") \
  .option("batchsize", "100000") \
  .option("schemaCheckEnabled", "false") \
  .save()
```

I am getting below error if using the mentioned connector.

```
    Error while Loading the data into a table -
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 28 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 28.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 54):
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

I have created a new cluster with the below configuration and only one library is installed in that cluster which is from maven coordinate - *com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0*

1. 8 Worker nodes with 14GB memory and 4 cores.
2. Databricks Runtime Version - 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2,
   scala 2.12).

Is there something else I can do to improve the performance as for around 100 million record old jdbc driver is taking around 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of the datetime datatype. SQL Server Datetime data type only allows 3 digits fractional seconds while spark dataframe might have more digits. Using datetime2 for SQL column instead of datetime resolved the issue.

[Reference](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/issues/204)